# SQL: Counting one to many relations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship

Given following tables:

- User(u_id,c_id)
- Color(c_id, color_name)

Assume that every user can only chose one color. How do you return (using SQL) a list of color names that have been chosen by more than 10 users?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
select color_name  
from User U  
left join Color C on U.c_id = C.c_id  
group by color_name  
having count(u_id) >= 10
```

Comment: First of all - write a propper join before answering.